# Which process generated specific DNS query?

Tags: process, dns, monitoring, macos

Context: I have a few Mac OS laptops, Catalina 10.15. I noticed suspicious DNS requests in our firewall  logs (capable of showing DNS queries), and traced the source IPs to these Mac Books. I checked the processes, and see nothing out of ordinary. Firewall shows that the connections to the IPs being responses to the queries are not established.

I tried to run tcpdump and Wireshark, and I confirmed these devices generate the DNS requests, but I could not pinpoint the specific process/application.

Question: How can I check which process is generating these DNS queries?
Additionally, as MacOS is POSIX-compliant, is the same technique applicable to any BSD or even Linux device?

Comment: Depending on how the lookups are being triggered, [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) might show them. But if there's no actual outgoing connection, I'm not sure it'll see whatever's causing the lookup.